# Verify Condition Array in panda

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset and contain football team and score.

I'm looking for the record of times in a row where there were less than 1.5 goals in the game.

I did that:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1920/F1.csv')
dh = df[['Date','HomeTeam','AwayTeam','FTHG','FTAG']]

# for all the match of one team
index_list = dh[(dh['HomeTeam'] == 'Paris SG') | (dh['AwayTeam'] == 'Paris SG')].index.tolist()
dh_psg = dh.iloc[index_list]
print(dh_psg)
```

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

1- it's the record-breaking streak of all time.

```
          Date     HomeTeam      AwayTeam    FTHG  FTAG
5   7/08/2019       Montpellier  Rennes       0     1
11  10/08/2019      Nantes       Montpellier  0     0
14  12/08/2019      Montpellier  Paris SG     1     0
16  14/08/2019      Toulouse     Montpellier  1     0
18  18/08/2019      Montpellier  Strasbourg   0     0

print("the record-breaking streak of all time is", 5)
```

2-this is the record-breaking sequel to by taking into account the last date.

```
          Date     HomeTeam      AwayTeam     FTHG  FTAG
17  19/08/2020     Montpellier   Dijon        1      0
18  22/08/2020     Montpellier   Strasbourg   0      0

print("the record-breaking sequel to by taking into account the last date is", 2)
```

Thank you for all your help

Comment: which columns do you use to determine that a match had less than 1.5 goals?

Comment: Please post sample input and the required output.

Comment: I'm looking to make a python program to help me make sports bets on over 1.5 goals.
For input it's a CSV file with match scores.
For the output I'm looking for a table or a variable to compare the record of all the times of a team and the current record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lt` and `agg`:

```
msk=df[['FTHG','FTAG']].agg(sum,1).lt(1.5)
df=df[msk]
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
          Date     HomeTeam    AwayTeam  FTHG  FTAG
5   10/08/2019  Montpellier      Rennes     0     1
11  17/08/2019       Nantes   Marseille     0     0
12  17/08/2019       Amiens       Lille     1     0
16  17/08/2019     Toulouse       Dijon     1     0
18  18/08/2019        Reims  Strasbourg     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm also looking for the record of more than 1.5 goals taking into account the date of the last game to be able to compare the two records.